# How to scroll a vertical text in table header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple table with vertical text in the header like:

[**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/zgxn2w7w/)

**HTML & CSS**

```css
div.vertical {
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 215px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

th.vertical {
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

div.vertical {
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 215px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

th.vertical {
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: left;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 1</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 2</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when I have lots of columns, the div wrapping the table scrolls and looks like this:

[**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/nfxm3p1v/)

But, as you might have noticed while scrolling the header is not scrolling at all. I found that I was using `position: absolute` in `div.vertical` class, due to which this was happening. But, if I remove that style then the header is scrolling, but the header width becomes large as you can see here:

[**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/nfxm3p1v/1/)

Is there any way we can we have both scrolling and small header width using CSS only? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `th.vertical`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/qykpe411/)

```css
div.vertical {
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 215px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

th.vertical {
  height: 220px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 1</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 2</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 2</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For infos : [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
.vertical {
  writing-mode:vertical-lr
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 10px;">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 1</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 2</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 3</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex</div>
            </th>
            <th class="vertical">
              <div class="vertical">Really long and complex 2</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
            <td>AH</td>
            <td>BH</td>
            <td>HH</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
```

similar answer : [Rotating Text Within A Fixed Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295450/rotating-text-within-a-fixed-div/38295735#38295735)