# CSS Text orientation : vertically oriented to the right

Tags: css

Is it possible to get my text oriented vertically to the right with CSS, like on the image below ?

[image]

I tried the way below, but without being able to reverse the orientation:

```css
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: sideways;
}
```

```html
<div>dimanche</div>
```

Comment: Always try to include an [mcve] in question

Comment: @SagarV Okay, I've added the reproductible example I tried before to my post.

Comment: what about `writing-mode:sideways-lr;` ?  A similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295450/rotating-text-within-a-fixed-div/38295735

Answer (score 29, accepted):

sideways isn't supported by all the browser. Instead you can replace it with a scale transformation

```css
div {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  /*text-orientation: sideways;*/
  transform:scale(-1);
}
```

```html
<div>dimanche</div>
```

Comment: Perfect answer ! Inspired by `@connexo`'s answer, I was going to try it but you were faster :)

Comment: Compatibility note: `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` is not supported by Edge and IE. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode). Need to use along with `-webkit-writing-mode: tb-rl; -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;` (former for Edge, latter for IE).

Answer (score 4):

rotate it by `-90deg` using `transform`. If you want it in the opposite direction, rotate it by `90deg`

```css
div {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<div>dimanche</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. No way to do it with `text-orientation: sideways;` ?

Comment: No. Because english can be written either from left to right or from top to bottom. The one you're mentioning is non-standard