# CSS: How to flip invert writing mode 'vertical-lr'

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to face my words in the opposite way (as if they were rotated 180 degrees) in my container.  I tried using `writing-mode: vertical-rl;` but it flips it in the way I don't want.

https://jsfiddle.net/cqy0px4a/2/

```css
*{
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid black;

  
}
.box{
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.something{
 
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
      <div class="something">
    Hello
  </div>
        <div class="something">
    Hello
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038952/8620333 ?

Comment: Yup that looks like it.  Simple but impossible to find when you're looking for it. thanks

Comment: 'sideways-lr' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

but only firefox support