# Align menu items after rotating -90 degree in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a navigation menu which the menu item is rotated -90 degree (see the screenshot):

[image: Screenshot]

I tried several ways in CSS, but the alignment is still incorrect. Here is the Fiddle I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/3rwe92ys/1/

The HTML used:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS used:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  position: relative;
}
.menu_item {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #F00;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
  margin: auto;
}
.menu_item span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

My question is: How can I align the text according to the screenshot? i.e. center-aligned in the `menu_item` DIV, and how do I apply `background-color` only under the menu text, e.g. the "MENU 1" instead of the `menu_item` itself? I wish the `span` sizes according to the text dimensions (i.e. autosizing like inline element), but can apply background color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038952/8620333 if you do it without rotation it would be easier

Comment: I tend to find this sort of thing easier if I rotate the whole outer element rather than each of the individual elements inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_item">
    <div>MENU 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <div>MENU 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <div>MENU 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <div>MENU 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  position: relative;
}
.menu_item {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #F00;
  width: 40px;
  height: 22%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 13%;
  margin-bottom: 13%;
  position: relative;
}
.menu_item div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: -10%;
  width: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Use this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vsvaibhav2016/tscz0La5/1/

Answer (score 3):

There you Go (Change style accordingly )

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 80px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #00F;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu_item {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #F00;
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #0F0;
    margin: 10px auto;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: column; */
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.menu_item span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin-left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="menu_item">
    <span>MENU 4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  top: 465px;
  left: -450px;
}
.menu_item {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #F00;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #0F0;
  margin: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
.menu_item span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)" 
before asking a question.