# How do I make rotated elements to occupate their new real space?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I applied transform property rotate() to set a text vertically, but after rotation it keeps its original dimensions.

In the image below the text "About Me" is the rotated h3 and the red box is his container div. As I say, it keeps using his original dimensions even after text is rotated, how I can change that?

[image: rotated text]

```css
const SectionTitle = styled.h3`
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-40%, 0);
  top: 0;
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #d8dee9ad;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  border: 1px solid red;
`
```

I have seen some solutions with jQuery but in this case I can't use jQuery. Also I am using styled-components on React.

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038952/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, that will works!