# Vertical Buttons List In UL>Li Using CSS transform: rotate

Tags: html, css, transform

I am trying to create a list of button/links in a menu bar `ul>li>a` tags using pure CSS3 `transform: rotate` as shown in the below image.

[image]

For this purpose, I tried the below code.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-1">General Info</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-2">Sites/Locations</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-3">Contacts</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-4">Registration</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-5">Affiliations</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-6">Bank Details</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-7">Finances</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-8">Notifications</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-9">Documents</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background:#FF0000;
}
.nav > li > a {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background ease 0.2s;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.71428571;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #f7fafc;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #ADADAD;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left bottom;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 0 -15px -75px;
}
```

That you can see live at **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2dby0t3q/)** The problem I am facing is the position of vertically setlists into their original position that is not currently happening. Can you help me out in this problem?

Comment: use writing-mode: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038952/8620333

Comment: Do you mean the buttons are not centred?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks a lot. You got me. Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/y57chqLj/ Please add this in the answer so I will mark that correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `writing-mode`

```css
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background: #FF0000;
}

.nav>li>a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  z-index: 1;
  order: 1;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background ease 0.2s;
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0 0 -1px 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.71428571;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #f7fafc;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #ADADAD;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: sideways;
  transform: scale(-1);
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-1">General Info</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-2">Sites/Locations</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-3">Contacts</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-4">Registration</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-5">Affiliations</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-6">Bank Details</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-7">Finances</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-8">Notifications</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-9">Documents</a></li>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the rotation position by changing here in CSS like this

```
transform-origin: left bottom;
```

```
transform-origin:top right;
```

Comment: Your answer is nearly the same but list is not keeping full parent DIV cover as shown in RED at: https://jsfiddle.net/6dzvjyrh/

Answer (score 0):

You're never going to get consistent spacing using rotations, use writing modes instead.

```css
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    background:#FF0000;
}
.nav > li > a {
    float: left;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    z-index: 1;
    order: 1;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background ease 0.2s;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.71428571;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #f7fafc;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #ADADAD;
    height: 80px;
    width: 20px;
    writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-1">General Info</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-2">Sites/Locations</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-3">Contacts</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-4">Registration</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-5">Affiliations</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-6">Bank Details</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-7">Finances</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-8">Notifications</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#tab-9">Documents</a></li>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
```

Comment: ... the text isn't rotated

Comment: I want the text should be rotated vertically also.

Comment: It's rotated for me?